# Cannot generate dates sequence in Matlab

Tags: matlab, datetime

I have start and end date in serial date number format. I want to have a vector of monthly increments between the two dates. I follow the descriptions and I don't get any errors but the resulting tt variable is an empty matrix:

```
t_start = datetime(datestr(736512));
t_end = datetime(datestr(730852));
tt = t_start:calmonths(1):t_end;
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your start and end dates are flipped.

```
t_start = 
   01-Jul-2016
t_end = 
   01-Jan-2001
```

This will work and create a 187 time-steps vector `tt`:

```
t_start = datetime(datestr(730852));
t_end = datetime(datestr(736512));
tt = t_start:calmonths(1):t_end;
```

if you want the vector to decrease in time, just flip it:

```
tt = fliplr(tt)
```

or generate it backwards:

```
tt = t_end:-calmonths(1):t_start;
```